# Add arbitrary Vue.js components to parent component

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, data-driven

I'm using Vue.js to build ui for my html5 game. I have a case where I want to define ui-containers which essentially just group other ui-components and position them to somewhere on screen. So I could have something like this going on:

```
<ui-container>
  <ui-component1></ui-component1>
  <ui-component2></ui-component2>
  <ui-component3></ui-component3>
</ui-container>
```

Where I need to add and remove those components dynamically based on data-model which represents the content of the container. The problem is that I'd like to keep ui-container generic, so that I can append any Vue-component to it without having information in template about which components there might be.

I googled and found this example which concerns injecting components dynamically: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/349/injecting-components-to-the-dom 
While the data-driven version in example was easy to make and understand, it uses v-for for  tag and therefore requires one to know before hand the type of child-component.

So question is, how I can generalize that example to work with any component dynamically? Should my data-model have the type of component or tag name of it and then interpolate it in v-for? Or is there existing mechanism for this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use special `is` attribute to dynamically set the type of a component. Here are the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). The code will look somewhat like:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="component in components" :is="component.type" :value="component.value"></div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle to play with: [Dynamic Vue.js components](https://jsfiddle.net/pkawiak/amockymp/)